# Global Components in Nuxt JS

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have built some components such as modals and reviews that I want to use and reuse just about everywhere in my site.

I have made a single `global.js` file in the plugins folder, So iv'e just registered this in my `nuxt.config.js` file once.

In my `global.js` file i've imported vue and called the components

```
import Vue from 'vue';
Vue.component('component-modal', () => import('@/components/modal'));
Vue.component('component-modal-other', () => import('@/components/modalOther'));
Vue.component('component-reviews', () => import('@/components/reviews'));
```

The reason for this is that now I don't have to do `component import` on every instance that I want to use it for I just call the component `<my-component>`.

However I've just switched to Universal mode and i'm now getting hydration warnings that are all coming from my `global.js` components file that I made in my plugins folder.

Should I not have a global.js file and each component that I want to use globally have it's own file in the plugins folder? Or do I just need to import the component when I need it locally in the file that is requiring it?

What is the best way to re-use and register global mini components that I have created?

**Vue Warning**

```
The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render
```

The only way I can avoid this warning is not to put my components into a `global.js` component file and register it with Nuxt plugins. Only use the component import into each instance which kind of defeats the purpose of global components

Comment: You can also use this community plugin: https://github.com/nuxt-community/global-components

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import Modal from '@/components/modal'
Vue.component('Modal', Modal)
```

in your view

```
</modal>
```

Comment: It's still the same hydration warning when I try this code inside on my global.js file. The only way I can avoid this is to have import component into every instance where I need it. ----"The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content"